# Moving X400 address to user's new mailbox, internal NDR

Tags: email, exchange-2010, ndr

We have a user who has had access to his old mailbox restricted by management. However, they want them to continue to receive mail in a new mailbox using the same SMTP address.

The situation is, the old and new mailboxes both exist, so internal mail is still going to the old mailbox when using the autocomplete feature in Outlook, for people that have typed the SMTP address previously.

What is the process for moving the X400 internal address from the old mailbox to the new one, so that we don't have to get the entire company to clear their autocomplete cache?

I have tried simply changing the X400 address on the new mailbox to match what it was on the old, but has proved fruitless. I have also added an X500 address matching the X400, but guess this is not correct.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I assume you've already moved the SMTP address. Can you not set the forwarding address on the old mailbox to the SMTP address?

Comment: It would be nice, but I don;t think that works as the internal addressing used by exchange is not the SMTP address, it is the X400 address. This means that anyone who has previously typed the address has an autocomplete entry which will no longer work, as it will be pointing to the x400 address ont he old mailbox.

Comment: Right. Mail to that X.400 address hits the old mailbox as expected. This mailbox's forwarding address is set to the SMTP address so Exchange routes the mail to that address. The email client has nothing to do with the forwarding.

Comment: Ah yes of course, this will certainly work. I was just trying to fully move it over now, so that if the old mailbox has to be completely removed, I didn't have to revisit this issue. Perhaps I will leave that for if/when that solution is needed. Please feel free to add the above as an answer and I will mark it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already moved the SMTP address, just set the forwarding address on the old mailbox to that SMTP address.
Mail to the X.400 address hits the old mailbox as expected. This mailbox's forwarding address is set to the SMTP address so Exchange routes the mail to that address.